# ddd-debugger error: updating display and takes too long to display

Tags: c++, c, ddd-debugger

my ddd debugger is taking too long to display, usually it didn't take so long. Anybody has any ideas why this is happening? Any setting or anything that is required to be configure.

Thanks !!

Comment: Might be the size of the program you're trying to debug?

Comment: No its not the size problem. It used to run quick on the same size program before.

Comment: What does it display when it does finally display?   Evidently one (or more) of your displayed items is huge and takes a moment to prepare.  I encountered this myself when I tried `graph display \`info variables\``, it took several seconds to process and display the huge number of global variables and whatnot.